# android PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP seems not to work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my recent project I'm hiding app icon from launcher by using COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED flag.
Here you can see code:

```
PackageManager packageManager = SettingsActivity.this.getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(SettingsActivity.this, MainScreen.class);

packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

This is launched when user press checkBox. But some how every time after like 10-15 seconds the app suddenly stop. With no error or message.

I don't understand it because I have used DONT_KILL_APP flag..

Any suggestions?

Comment: What makes you think that this has anything to do with the code that you have shown here? Is your app in the foreground at the time? If not, Android can terminate your process at any point while it is in the background.

Comment: Its because app stops only after using that code.. Its kind of same time witch it takes to hide icon from launcher menu. If I dont set it to DISABLED it doesnt happens. Do you think the problem might be that I am accidentally calling it when its already DISABLED ?

Comment: "Its because app stops only after using that code" -- what does "app stops" mean?

Comment: I have an activity where is check box, when chceck box is checked the code above is executed. When unchecked, the same code with COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED is executed.  But when I check that box and wait like 10-15 seconds, the app window disappears with no warning or error message, also app disappear from recent apps and icon is hidden.

Comment: Is the activity that you are disabling the one that has the checkbox and is in the foreground when it vanishes? Or is it some other activity that you are disabling?

Comment: SettingsActivity is in foreground, and contains the check box. I'm disabling MainScreen activity because its the launch activity and I want to just hide app icon and don't know any other way how to do that.

Comment: That's really bizarre. I'll try to run some tests to see if I can reproduce this problem this week. Have you tried this on more than one Android environment (e.g., multiple devices, or a device and an emulator)?

Comment: Tested on android 5.0 LG G3 and 5.1 Nvidia tegra note.. and its the same. I do really appreciate your help.   ..weird is that it's the same as if I dont use DONT_KILL_APP flag and just set it to 0 but the difference is 10 sec delay before it kills app.

Comment: Well, I can reproduce the problem. It's been around since 5.0; I can't reproduce the problem on 4.4. It doesn't seem task-related, as I tried having my first activity use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when launching the second activity, but both activities were force-finished anyway. I don't know why it's doing this, but other than it being different than what it used to be, I don't know that this is strictly a bug. However, [somebody else filed a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194353) that seems related.

Comment: Hope they will fix it...  Do you know any other way how to hide icon from launcher?

Comment: You could try putting your `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` on an `<activity-alias>` that points to the actual launcher activity. Then, disable the alias. Since I do not know why the whole back stack is getting force-finished in the first place, I do not know if disabling an `activity-alias` instead of the underlying activity will help, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

First get your apps package name:

```
String packageName = activity.getPackageName();
```

Then set **clsDefault** from the name you must have defined in your  in your Manifest file.

```
 <activity-alias
            android:name=".HomeScreen-Default"...>

public static String clsDefault = packageName + ".HomeScreen-Default";
```

Then use this to set the icon.

```
activity.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(packageName, clsDefault ),
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```