# Android: PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP not preventing the app from closing when <activity-alias> is enabled

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I have created an `<activity-alias>` with a deprecation launch icon and I am enabling the alias when a deprecation error is received from the backend while at the same time disabling the original launch activity. When the error is detected, the original launch icon changes to the deprecation launch icon as expected, however, even though I use `PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP`, the application closes. Here is how I am enabling and disabling the activity alias and launch activity:

```
    private fun disableDefaultIcon() {
        val defComponentName = ComponentName(applicationContext.packageName, LaunchActivity::class.java.name)
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            defComponentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )
    }

    private fun enableDeprecatedIcon() {
        val depComponentName = ComponentName(applicationContext.packageName, "com.company.mon.AliasDeprecatedActivity")
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            depComponentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )
    }
```

I have also tried creating an `<activity-alias>` with the original launch icon that targets the launch activity instead of disabling the launch activity directly, but I still see the same behavior, the app closes, the icon changes, and there are no errors. Here is the code for the second approach:

```
        <!-- Activity Alias -->
        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.company.mon.AliasDefaultActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:targetActivity=".presentation.workflow.authentication.launch.LaunchActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.company.mon.AliasDeprecatedActivity"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:icon="${round_deprecated_icon_path}"
            android:roundIcon="${round_deprecated_icon_path}"
            android:targetActivity=".presentation.workflow.authentication.launch.LaunchActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

```
    private fun enableDeprecatedIcon() {
        val depComponentName = ComponentName(applicationContext.packageName, "com.company.mon.AliasDeprecatedActivity")
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            depComponentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )
    }

    private fun disableDefaultIcon() {
        val defComponentName = ComponentName(applicationContext.packageName, "com.company.mon.AliasDefaultActivity")
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            defComponentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )
    }
```

Based on the below posts, it seems like this may be a bug with `PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP` but I was wondering if anyone knows of any workarounds.

[android PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP seems to not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112301/android-packagemanager-dont-kill-app-seems-to-not-work)

[Application getting closed on the : setComponentEnabledSetting() with COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED and PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663748/application-getting-closed-on-the-setcomponentenabledsetting-with-component)

Answer (score 1):

I was recently trying to do the same thing, but unfortunately I don't think there is a workaround for it. Someone at Google mentioned it is an intended behavior: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279505991#comment21

I haven't seen any app that does this smoothly without killing an app. Telegram does it in a way that when you change the icon it saves the screen you were on before changing the icon. I suppose the only option to do this is inform the user that icon will be change and that "restart is required".

Comment: Thank you Sava. In the link that you shared it seems like the issue being reported and being marked as intended behavior is the fact that the app icon is not changing when the launch icon is changed. The Google developer does not explicitly state that the DONT_KILL_APP not working and the app closing is intended behavior.